# Scale up ElasticBeanStalk environment programmatically

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

How to add more instances (scale up)  ElasticBeanStalk environment programmatically within a running application (Spring Boot) ?

I thought of using AWSElasticBeanstalkClient, but couldn't find any method to add instances using the client.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticbeanstalk/AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.html

Any hints?

I need this because the design of my applications is that each App node needs to communicate with each other to perform some image-recognition tasks.

If this is not possible with EBS, I was thinking of creating EC2 programmatically as mentioned below, my problem is how to deploy my application to newly created EC2 instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/run-instance.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [updateEnvironment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticbeanstalk/AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.html#updateEnvironment-com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.UpdateEnvironmentRequest-) method to update the minimum and maximum values for the number of instances. That's in case you can't configure any automatic scaling triggers as strongjz suggested.

Comment: What if you want the min to stay the same but you want a temporary increase of the actual current count?

Answer (score 6):

Cloudwatch alarms + AutoScaling is the AWS Reference architecture for scaling your ElasticBeanstalk applications.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html

You can have each app node publish custom cloudwatch metrics and scale your ASG based on that.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html